# How to add /home/user/public_html as virtual host in apache - centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, httpd, httpd.conf

In Directadmin (I used it before) when we create a reseller, a new user with a home directory was created and user could add domains in a home directory like /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html

How i can add /home/user/public_html as virtual host to apache web server? I want to config apache like direct admin to use home directory.

Im new on Centos 6.5 and i'm trying to config a web server.
My OS is clear (no any configs, just DNS) and SElinux is disabled in /etc/sysconfig/selinux.
I have one ip for my VPS.

Now my config for httpd is below.

```
<VirtualHost domain-1.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/domains/domain-1.com/public_html
    ServerName domain-1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When i add this config, i get forbbiden error in `http://domain-1.com` and `http://server-ip`

**UPDATE**
I added the following code to apache conf.d but the error is alive.

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir enabled user
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

Comment: This will almost certainly be SELinux httpd_enable_homedirs

Comment: @Iain I see that page, my permission for public_html is (drwxr-xr-x 751), why i cant change it using chmod 755 public_html as root access?

Comment: the perms you show above are 755 so you won't see them changing ...

Comment: I think you should stop what you're doing and go read some documentation on Unix permissions and how they interact with the filesystem and processes.

Comment: @Iain Just i confused for the error, i understand permission reading was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on the error message in your log files, a missing IndexDocument i.e. no index.html in the documentroot could be one obvious cause for that error.

The other common cause would be because you have SELinux enabled. Check that with `getenforce`.

And of course file system privileges on the path to the documentroot i.e. on `/home/user` and `/home/user/domains/<etc>`

Comment: I change selinux to disable by `setenforce 0` and changing /etc/sysconfig/selinux to disable. but error happen again.

Comment: getenforce = disabled.

Comment: before adding VirtualHost, `http://server-ip` worked fine. but after it both of them given forbidden error.

Comment: And nothing useful in the apache error log?

Comment: just this error: `(13)Permission denied: access to / denied`

Comment: That is the error code for a file system permissions problem (One can check with `perror 13`). Quite useful. Check if the apache user can access the DocumentRoot with  `ls -ld /home/user /home/user/domains/ /home/user/domains/domain-1.com /home/user/domains/domain-1.com/index*`

Comment: I tyred to login as apache user with `su apache` but it is not possible, how i can do this?

Comment: The apache user typically has no valid shell, which is why you can't use `su apache`, what you can do is (as root) `sudo -u apache ls -ld /home/user  /home/user/domains/` etc. But just checking owners groups and permissions of the directories and files doesn't have to be done as apache, root or even user would work just as well.

Comment: There is a problem with `/home/user/domains` permission. I change it by `chmod 777 /home/user/domains` to solved the problem. Thanks ;)